# Azure Function deployed via Azure DevOps pipeline not executing

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-function-app

I have created an azure pipeline to deploy a custom docker image with an azure function with the following config. Though the config works in terms of build but none of the functions are running on the server and I notice that in the logs that none of the functions are being detected.

```yaml
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'build: build the docker image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'Azure subscription 1 (3fc75102-5159-4491-b61c-b3fcb845f648)'
    azureContainerRegistry: whaiiapp.azurecr.io
    imageName: 'azureapp.azurecr.io/puppeteer:$(Build.BuildId)'
    useDefaultContext: false

- task: Docker@1
  displayName: 'push the image'
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'Azure subscription 1 (3fc75102-5159-4491-b61c-b3fcb845f648)'
    azureContainerRegistry: azureapp.azurecr.io
    command: 'Push an image'
    imageName: 'azureap.azurecr.io/puppeteer:$(Build.BuildId)'

- task: FuncToolsInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install func tools - latest'

- task: AzureFunctionAppContainer@1
  displayName: 'Start Azure Function App on Container Deploy: generate-report-dev'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1 (3fc75102-5159-4491-b61c-b3fcb845f648)'
    appName: 'generate-report-dev'
    imageName: azureapp.azurecr.io/puppeteer
    containerCommand: 'npm start'
```

The following is my Dockerfile config

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-appservice

# Chromium dependencies
RUN apt-get update -yq \
&& apt-get install -yq git git-extras gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst libgbm-dev \
ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget && \
wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i dumb-init_*.deb && rm -f dumb-init_*.deb && \
apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot

RUN npm install --no-save puppeteer

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=node \

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && npm install

CMD [ "npm start" ]
```

I am not sure how I could go about debugging this. I tried logging into the server via ssh and running func start to test it and it shows func command is not available.

Comment: So your build was successful? I see that the configuration of your yaml file is also correct. Is there the same issue when trying to build and deploy locally?

Comment: hi, the deployment goes live but the functions are not detected. I have run the same docker image locally and it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe your azure function is unable to pull the image from your registry, I did faced the same issue, so I simply created new function app, then selected the repository in deployment process, so it is going to create a webhook behind the scene, that will pull the latest image from a registry, every time whenever it is updated.